# React router - set correctly useParams for detail page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Probably this will be some small mistake but I really can't find out why it's not working.

I have react app and when It's initialized, it gets data from Pokéapi a set it to redux state.

While getting this data, `<Intro />` component is shown. If downloading is over, page will redirect to `/home` and `listPokemons` component will render some of the results like this.

**Main view - listPokemons**

```
 result =  allPokemons.slice(0,9).map( (pokemon,i) => 

 <Link to={`/pokemon/${pokemon.id}`}>
    <Pokemon 
        key={i} 
        name={pokemon.name} 
        image={pokemon.image}
        type={pokemon.type}
        abilities={pokemon.abilities}
     />
 </Link>
```

So after click on some of the rendered Pokemons, location will change to /pokemon/id of pokemon.. This part is working.

**In my app.js**

```
<Router>
   {isLoading ? <Redirect exact to="/intro" /> : <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />}

   <Route exact path="/intro">
         <IntroView />
   </Route>

   <Route exact path="/home">
        <MainView />
   </Route>

   <Route path="/pokemon/:id">
       <PokemonOverview />
   </Route>
</Router>
```

So If I understand It right, if one of the pokemons is clicked, `<PokemonOverview />` will render and is supposed to display data for that clicked pokemon. But it's not working.

**PokemonOverview component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const PokemonOverview = () =>{
    const allPokemons = useSelector(state => state.AllPokemons);
    const {id} = useParams();
    const thisPokemon = allPokemons.map(pokemon => pokemon.id === id)

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>{thisPokemon.name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PokemonOverview;
```

I don't know if this approach is correct but I'm not receiving any data in this component. I've followed some tutorials on youtube and everybody did this the same way. If I've tried to change value of `<h1>` for example to ' hello there ' ,it displays correctly after click on one of the listed pokemons..

What Am I doing wrong? Please help me someone . I'm looking everywhere and can't find anything how to do that :/

Comment: Can you post what you get when `console.log(allPokemons)` and `console.log(id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please check what are you getting for "id", at `const {id} = useParams();`.

Then, please check what is "allPokemons" you get from `const allPokemons = useSelector(state => state.AllPokemons);`. If "allPokemons” is an Object then `const thisPokemon = allPokemons.map(pokemon => pokemon.id === id)` won't work proper. This map logic only works if "allPokemons" is an Array.

At last, please check the data type for "id" in `pokemon.id === id`. The "id" could be a string type, but if "pokemon.id" is a number type then the check will fail, event when "id" is correct. For example, `10 === "10"` is `false`. If this is the case you can wrap "id" with `parseInt(id)` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,as soon as I will be on computer I will try it . It seems I don’t clearly know what useparams do. If i get it right,it takes current url,for example /pokemon/3 ,so {Id} = useparams will be 3? Or how I’m supposed to pass that Id ?  Thank you.

Comment: I highly suspect the id is a string type. You can try to print out the result of `pokemon.id === id` and the value of `id`.  Since the "id" is get from the url it could be "3" (string) instead of 3 (number), this will make the "===" fail.

Comment: I will try it in a moment l and I will let you know .

Comment: You were right, {id} was string and id from allPokemons was number. Thank you. But I have another problem. If I click on pokemon,url changes, but his infomation displays under listed pokemons. I mean listed pokemons component doesnt unload

Comment: @Pinncik Sorry for the late response. Do you have the issue solved yet?

Comment: Yes, you were right. Id of pokemon was number and Id from params was string :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

allPokemons.find(pokemon => pokemon.id === id)

Edit:
map and filter will always return an array. So if we want just one item we should use array.find

Comment: It returns empty array

Comment: Can you add a sample of pokemon array?

Comment: returns undefined :/

Comment: Do you mean state where are All pokemons? Sure,
{id(pin):10
name(pin):"Caterpie"
image(pin):"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/10.png"
type(pin):"bug"}

Comment: @Pinncik have you checked if you are getting the value of id correctly or not ?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere with getting the id value. Because I'm not getting anything. That's why I get undefined. Why Am I now getting anything? ..

Comment: Try useState to set value in heading.

Comment: @Pinncik use a console.log to see if you are getting a defined id or not